# Read JSON nested array response to avoid Duplicate entries in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

how to read below JSON properly to store in Model

```
{
  "data": {
        "success": "true",
        "orders": [
            {
                "orderId": "5",
                "prefix": "OID-MKFQ7-00000",
                "status": "C",
                "createdOn": "2018-03-30 16:21:59",
                "createdBy": "1016",
                "tax": "21.20",
                "shippingCharges": "0.00",
                "deliveryCode": "",
                "shopId": "3",
                "amount": "291.2",
                "subTotal": "270",
                "discount": "0",
                "couponCode": "",
                "productDetails": [
                    {
                        "productId": "44",
                        "storeId": "3",
                        "productName": "Tata Sampann Toor Dal ",
                        "quantity": "5",
                        "productAmount": "54.00",
                        "totalAmount": 270,
                        "optionDetails": {
                            "optionId": "49",
                            "optionName": "Available in (Units):500 gm",
                            "optionAmount": "54"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "userAddressDetails": {
                    "firstName": "",
                    "middleName": "",
                    "lastName": "",
                    "email": "9284314578@mailinator.com",
                    "mobileNo": "9284314578",
                    "address": "Savali Society Rd",
                    "landMark": "Industrial Estate",
                    "city": "Ichalkaranji",
                    "zipCode": "416117",
                    "stateName": "Maharashtra",
                    "countryName": "India",
                    "latitude": "16.719247500000016",
                    "longitude": "74.45389453124999"
                }
            },
            {
                "orderId": "6",
                "prefix": "OID-G4KHX-00000",
                "status": "C",
                "createdOn": "2018-04-10 17:45:22",
                "createdBy": "1011",
                "tax": "42.41",
                "shippingCharges": "0.00",
                "deliveryCode": "",
                "shopId": "3",
                "amount": "582.41",
                "subTotal": "540",
                "discount": "0",
                "couponCode": "",
                "productDetails": [
                    {
                        "productId": "44",
                        "storeId": "3",
                        "productName": "Tata Sampann Toor Dal ",
                        "quantity": "10",
                        "productAmount": "54.00",
                        "totalAmount": 540,
                        "optionDetails": {
                            "optionId": "49",
                            "optionName": "Available in (Units):500 gm",
                            "optionAmount": "54"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "userAddressDetails": {
                    "firstName": "test",
                    "middleName": "",
                    "lastName": "test",
                    "email": "test@test.com",
                    "mobileNo": "8446363349",
                    "address": "New Shahupuri, 204, Kolhapur Station Rd",
                    "landMark": "Tarabai Park",
                    "city": "Kolhapur",
                    "zipCode": "416001",
                    "stateName": "Maharashtra",
                    "countryName": "India",
                    "latitude": "16.704987299999996",
                    "longitude": "74.24325270000001"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried

```
{
                final JSONObject output = response.getJSONObject("data");

                if (output.getString("success").equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                    final JSONArray orderDetails = output.getJSONArray("orders");

                    for (int i = 0; i < orderDetails.length(); i++) {
                        // Get single order object
                        JSONObject orderData = orderDetails.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Get product details object
                        JSONArray products = orderData.getJSONArray("productDetails");
                        for (int k = 0; k < products.length(); k++) {
                            JSONObject productData = products.getJSONObject(k);

                            JSONObject optionData = productData.getJSONObject("optionDetails");

                            ProductDetailsModel product = new ProductDetailsModel(
                                    productData.getString("productId"),
                                    productData.getString("storeId"),
                                    productData.getString("productName"),
                                    productData.getString("quantity"),
                                    productData.getString("productAmount"),
                                    productData.getString("totalAmount"),
                                    optionData.getString("optionId"),
                                    optionData.getString("optionName"),
                                    optionData.getString("optionAmount")
                            );
                            productsList.add(product);

                            //System.out.println(productsList);

                            for (int j =0; j< productsList.size(); j++){
                                System.out.println("Hey data: "+productsList.get(j).getQuantity());
                            }
                        }

                        // Get user address object
                        JSONObject userAddress = orderData.getJSONObject("userAddressDetails");
                        UserAddressDetailsModel addressModel = new UserAddressDetailsModel(
                                userAddress.getString("firstName"), userAddress.getString("middleName"),
                                userAddress.getString("lastName"), userAddress.getString("email"),
                                userAddress.getString("mobileNo"), userAddress.getString("address"),
                                userAddress.getString("landMark"), userAddress.getString("city"),
                                userAddress.getString("zipCode"), userAddress.getString("stateName"),
                                userAddress.getString("countryName"), userAddress.getString("latitude"),
                                userAddress.getString("longitude"));

                        ordersList.add(addressModel);

                        Order order = new Order(orderData.getString("tax"),
                                orderData.getString("shippingCharges"),
                                orderData.getString("amount"),
                                orderData.getString("subTotal"),
                                orderData.getString("discount"),
                                orderData.getString("prefix"),
                                orderData.getString("createdOn"),
                                orderData.getString("couponCode"),
                                orderData.getString("orderId"),
                                orderData.getString("deliveryCode"),
                                orderData.getString("shopId"),
                                orderData.getString("createdBy"),
                                orderData.getString("status"),
                                productsList, addressModel);

                        orders.add(order);

                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), output.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }
```

it result duplicate entries in child(**productDetails**) json array  of nested parent(**orders**) json array.

Comment: your json is invalid check it here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @NileshRathod check edited question and yes it valid json...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: Why don't you use Retrofit if you want to store in Model?

Comment: @LuvnishMonga I'm not that much familier to Retrofit if help me to how to implement I'll do :)

Comment: Follow this link: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Comment: @LuvnishMonga thank you for help and time. I  do it in Volley first if do'nt work I'll try  Retrofit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(readJSONFromAsset());

        JSONObject mainJsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");

        String success = mainJsonObject.getString("success");

        JSONArray orders = mainJsonObject.getJSONArray("orders");

        for (int i = 0; i < orders.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject orderJsonObject = orders.getJSONObject(i);
            String orderId=orderJsonObject.getString("orderId");
            String prefix=orderJsonObject.getString("prefix");
            String status=orderJsonObject.getString("status");
            String createdOn=orderJsonObject.getString("createdOn");
            String createdBy=orderJsonObject.getString("createdBy");
            String tax=orderJsonObject.getString("tax");
            String shippingCharges=orderJsonObject.getString("shippingCharges");
            String deliveryCode=orderJsonObject.getString("deliveryCode");
            String shopId=orderJsonObject.getString("shopId");
            String amount=orderJsonObject.getString("amount");
            String subTotal=orderJsonObject.getString("subTotal");
            String discount=orderJsonObject.getString("discount");
            String couponCode=orderJsonObject.getString("couponCode");

            JSONArray productDetails=orderJsonObject.getJSONArray("productDetails");

            for (int j=0;j<productDetails.length();j++){
                JSONObject productDeatilObject=productDetails.getJSONObject(j);

                String productId=productDeatilObject.getString("productId");
                String storeId=productDeatilObject.getString("storeId");
                String productName=productDeatilObject.getString("productName");
                String quantity=productDeatilObject.getString("quantity");
                String productAmount=productDeatilObject.getString("productAmount");
                String totalAmount=productDeatilObject.getString("totalAmount");

                JSONObject optionDetails=productDeatilObject.getJSONObject("optionDetails");

                String optionId=optionDetails.getString("optionId");
                String optionName=optionDetails.getString("optionName");
                String optionAmount=optionDetails.getString("optionAmount");
            }

            JSONObject userAddressDetails=orderJsonObject.getJSONObject("userAddressDetails");
            String firstName=userAddressDetails.getString("firstName");
            String middleName=userAddressDetails.getString("middleName");
            String lastName=userAddressDetails.getString("lastName");
            String email=userAddressDetails.getString("email");
            String mobileNo=userAddressDetails.getString("mobileNo");
            String address=userAddressDetails.getString("address");
            String landMark=userAddressDetails.getString("landMark");
            String city=userAddressDetails.getString("city");
            String zipCode=userAddressDetails.getString("zipCode");
            String stateName=userAddressDetails.getString("stateName");
            String countryName=userAddressDetails.getString("countryName");
            String latitude=userAddressDetails.getString("latitude");
            String longitude=userAddressDetails.getString("longitude");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**EDIT**

You can use [**`Gson`**](https://github.com/google/gson) to parse your `JSON`

> `Gson` is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their `JSON` representation. It can also be used to convert a `JSON` string to an equivalent Java object. `Gson` can work with arbitrary Java objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of.

Create pojo class using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

**SAMPLE POJO CLASS of your response**

> Data class

```
public class Data {

    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private String success;
    @SerializedName("orders")
    @Expose
    private List<Order> orders = null;

    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public List<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(List<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

}
```

> Example class

```
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private Data data;

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

> OptionDetails class

```
public class OptionDetails {

    @SerializedName("optionId")
    @Expose
    private String optionId;
    @SerializedName("optionName")
    @Expose
    private String optionName;
    @SerializedName("optionAmount")
    @Expose
    private String optionAmount;

    public String getOptionId() {
        return optionId;
    }

    public void setOptionId(String optionId) {
        this.optionId = optionId;
    }

    public String getOptionName() {
        return optionName;
    }

    public void setOptionName(String optionName) {
        this.optionName = optionName;
    }

    public String getOptionAmount() {
        return optionAmount;
    }

    public void setOptionAmount(String optionAmount) {
        this.optionAmount = optionAmount;
    }

}
```

> Order class

```
public class Order {

    @SerializedName("orderId")
    @Expose
    private String orderId;
    @SerializedName("prefix")
    @Expose
    private String prefix;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("createdOn")
    @Expose
    private String createdOn;
    @SerializedName("createdBy")
    @Expose
    private String createdBy;
    @SerializedName("tax")
    @Expose
    private String tax;
    @SerializedName("shippingCharges")
    @Expose
    private String shippingCharges;
    @SerializedName("deliveryCode")
    @Expose
    private String deliveryCode;
    @SerializedName("shopId")
    @Expose
    private String shopId;
    @SerializedName("amount")
    @Expose
    private String amount;
    @SerializedName("subTotal")
    @Expose
    private String subTotal;
    @SerializedName("discount")
    @Expose
    private String discount;
    @SerializedName("couponCode")
    @Expose
    private String couponCode;
    @SerializedName("productDetails")
    @Expose
    private List<ProductDetail> productDetails = null;
    @SerializedName("userAddressDetails")
    @Expose
    private UserAddressDetails userAddressDetails;

    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public String getPrefix() {
        return prefix;
    }

    public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(String createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public String getTax() {
        return tax;
    }

    public void setTax(String tax) {
        this.tax = tax;
    }

    public String getShippingCharges() {
        return shippingCharges;
    }

    public void setShippingCharges(String shippingCharges) {
        this.shippingCharges = shippingCharges;
    }

    public String getDeliveryCode() {
        return deliveryCode;
    }

    public void setDeliveryCode(String deliveryCode) {
        this.deliveryCode = deliveryCode;
    }

    public String getShopId() {
        return shopId;
    }

    public void setShopId(String shopId) {
        this.shopId = shopId;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getSubTotal() {
        return subTotal;
    }

    public void setSubTotal(String subTotal) {
        this.subTotal = subTotal;
    }

    public String getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    public void setDiscount(String discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    public String getCouponCode() {
        return couponCode;
    }

    public void setCouponCode(String couponCode) {
        this.couponCode = couponCode;
    }

    public List<ProductDetail> getProductDetails() {
        return productDetails;
    }

    public void setProductDetails(List<ProductDetail> productDetails) {
        this.productDetails = productDetails;
    }

    public UserAddressDetails getUserAddressDetails() {
        return userAddressDetails;
    }

    public void setUserAddressDetails(UserAddressDetails userAddressDetails) {
        this.userAddressDetails = userAddressDetails;
    }

}
```

> ProductDetail class

```
public class ProductDetail {

    @SerializedName("productId")
    @Expose
    private String productId;
    @SerializedName("storeId")
    @Expose
    private String storeId;
    @SerializedName("productName")
    @Expose
    private String productName;
    @SerializedName("quantity")
    @Expose
    private String quantity;
    @SerializedName("productAmount")
    @Expose
    private String productAmount;
    @SerializedName("totalAmount")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalAmount;
    @SerializedName("optionDetails")
    @Expose
    private OptionDetails optionDetails;

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getStoreId() {
        return storeId;
    }

    public void setStoreId(String storeId) {
        this.storeId = storeId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getProductAmount() {
        return productAmount;
    }

    public void setProductAmount(String productAmount) {
        this.productAmount = productAmount;
    }

    public Integer getTotalAmount() {
        return totalAmount;
    }

    public void setTotalAmount(Integer totalAmount) {
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
    }

    public OptionDetails getOptionDetails() {
        return optionDetails;
    }

    public void setOptionDetails(OptionDetails optionDetails) {
        this.optionDetails = optionDetails;
    }

}
```

> UserAddressDetails class

```
public class UserAddressDetails {

    @SerializedName("firstName")
    @Expose
    private String firstName;
    @SerializedName("middleName")
    @Expose
    private String middleName;
    @SerializedName("lastName")
    @Expose
    private String lastName;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("mobileNo")
    @Expose
    private String mobileNo;
    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    private String address;
    @SerializedName("landMark")
    @Expose
    private String landMark;
    @SerializedName("city")
    @Expose
    private String city;
    @SerializedName("zipCode")
    @Expose
    private String zipCode;
    @SerializedName("stateName")
    @Expose
    private String stateName;
    @SerializedName("countryName")
    @Expose
    private String countryName;
    @SerializedName("latitude")
    @Expose
    private String latitude;
    @SerializedName("longitude")
    @Expose
    private String longitude;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMobileNo() {
        return mobileNo;
    }

    public void setMobileNo(String mobileNo) {
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getLandMark() {
        return landMark;
    }

    public void setLandMark(String landMark) {
        this.landMark = landMark;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getStateName() {
        return stateName;
    }

    public void setStateName(String stateName) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

}
```

> than parse using **`Gson`** like below code

```
    String apiResponse = readJSONFromAsset();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    Example resultObj = gson.fromJson(apiResponse, Example.class);

    ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    orders.addAll(resultObj.getData().getOrders());


    Log.e("_SIZE",  orders.size()+"_SIZE");

    for (int i = 0; i < orders.size(); i++) {

        Log.e("resultOb", orders.get(i).getAmount()+"amount");
        Log.e("resultOb", orders.get(i).getCouponCode()+"getCouponCode");
        Log.e("resultOb", orders.get(i).getDeliveryCode()+"getDeliveryCode");


        for (int j=0;j<orders.get(i).getProductDetails().size();j++){
            Log.e("resultOb", orders.get(i).getProductDetails().get(j).getTotalAmount() + "");
            Log.e("resultOb", orders.get(i).getProductDetails().get(j).getProductId() + "");
            Log.e("resultOb", orders.get(i).getProductDetails().get(j).getProductName() + "");
            Log.e("resultOb", orders.get(i).getProductDetails().get(j).getQuantity() + "");
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks for response!  already tried  this but prints duplicate values of **productDetails** JSONArray in adapter class... :(

Comment: thank you mate! Gson works like charm in Nested JSON array ...:)

Answer (score 1):

Do this. I made this and it is working seamlessly.

```
      RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="http://www.mocky.io/v2/5affc3ae310000970076de82";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                      //  Log.e("response",response);
                        try {
                            JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);

                            JSONObject data= res.getJSONObject("data");
                            String success=data.getString("success");
                            if (success.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                                JSONArray array=data.getJSONArray("orders");

                                for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                                    JSONObject jsonObject=array.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String orderid=jsonObject.getString("orderId");
                                    String prefix=jsonObject.getString("prefix");
                                    String status=jsonObject.getString("status");
                                    String createdOn=jsonObject.getString("createdOn");
                                    String tax=jsonObject.getString("tax");
                                    String shippingCharges=jsonObject.getString("shippingCharges");

                                    JSONArray productDetails=jsonObject.getJSONArray("productDetails");

                                    for (int j=0;j<productDetails.length();j++){
                                        JSONObject prdet=productDetails.getJSONObject(j);
                                        String productId=prdet.getString("productId");
                                        Log.e("productId",productId);

                                        JSONObject optionDetails=prdet.getJSONObject("optionDetails");
                                        String optionId=optionDetails.getString("optionId");
                                        Log.e("optionId",optionId);

                                        JSONObject userAddressDetails= jsonObject.getJSONObject("userAddressDetails");
                                        String email=userAddressDetails.getString("email");
                                        Log.e("email",email);

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: thank you for  your help ,  this is not working for me.

Comment: no your code is ok but this I already tried so **productDetails** PRINT duplicate entries....

Comment: You have already achieved what you wanted, but I you want I can provide the JSON implementation of this in recyclerview through model class. Shall I do?